# problem with nvidia driver

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-settings

I am using NVIDIA binary driver version 346.96 and when I try to change my graphic card it doesnt work. It asks me to log out and log in but after that it is back switched to intel.
I have acer aspire nvidia gt650m and intel HD Graphic 4000 Ivi bridge
I had installed driver correctly but after I reinstalled the drier I gave this problem.

```
boris@boris-Aspire-V3-771:~$ lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D' 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
  Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 0686
  Kernel driver in use: i915  
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 650M] (rev a1)
  Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 0686
07:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5209 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: I was looking for answer here but nothing I have found here worked for me. I was reinstalling driver because of playing crysis 2 and I installed bublebee and got error abou my nvidia graphic card so I reinstalled driver and now I am not able to switch to nvidia graphic card

Comment: And? Is that the reason not to give the required output?

Comment: boris@boris-Aspire-V3-771:~$ lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
 Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 0686
 Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 650M] (rev a1)
 Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 0686
07:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5209 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)

Comment: Please EDIT YOUR QUESTION and add the output there.

Comment: I reinstalled it and I switched graphic card then I rebooted my pc now when I turn on ubuntu I can see only background of ubuntu desktop no icon or anything.

Comment: Did the driver install without errors?

Comment: Yes but I am not able to turn on my ubuntu when I start my computer everything goes ok but when I get to ubuntu screen I cant do anything there are no icons only background image. I had to turn of my pc by holding powerbutton.

Answer (score 1):

Your graphics driver is not installed. You need to re-install it properly.
Run in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get purge bumblebee
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nvidia-346 nvidia-prime
```

If there are any errors, post them to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Prime Indicator](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/prime-indicator-lets-you-quickly-switch.html) to switch between Intel or Nvidia

And make sure you have selected Nvidia proprietary drivers in Additional Drivers

[image]

*I have selected the proprietary drivers*